# Permission issue when initiating ACTION_CALL from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, android-permissions

Im trying to intercept outgoing calls from device and force the user to select a calling app (even when a default app was selected).

I did this by defining a receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="com.myapp.OutgoingCallsReceiver" >
    <intent-filter android:priority="0">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and the code of the receiver is:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String destinationNumber = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER);

    setResultData(null);
    abortBroadcast();

    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + destinationNumber));
    callIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER, destinationNumber);

    Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(callIntent, "How do you want to make this call?");
    chooserIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    context.startActivity(chooserIntent);
}
```

When a call is being made i do see the app chooser dialog (on my device, with native dialer, skype and my app), but when selecting the native dialer from that dialog i get the following exception:

> 07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345): Writing exception to parcel
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345): **java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL**
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManagerService.java:13140)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at android.app.ActivityManager.handleIncomingUser(ActivityManager.java:2038)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at com.android.providers.settings.SettingsProvider.callFromPackage(SettingsProvider.java:607)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.call(ContentProvider.java:279)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:273)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:388)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at com.android.server.SystemServer.init1(Native Method)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:2012)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: E/DatabaseUtils(2345):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   07-31 12:33:46.125: W/ActivityManager(2345): Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL

Why is this happening ? Why do i need this special permission ? Any idea how to solve this ?
Thanks.

**Edit:**
Generalizing my question a bit more - in what cases it is possible to initate an outgoing call using ACTION_CALL ? why in those cases this INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL permission is not needed (im assuming it is not needed since it is not mentioned in the docs in conjunction with ACTION_CALL) ? Also, i would really appreciate any other solution/workaround for this issue. Dont know why a simple requirement like this need to be such a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need a special permission because the `ACTION_CALL` is a protected action, allow you to call a phone number directly, with no interaction from the user.  That's a security risk so it is "protected" by a permission.  You'll also notice that `Manifest.permission` doesn't define that permission publicly: that is intentional within the system.

Comment: So what can be done here ? Does adding this permission have any implications i should worry about ? If so, can you think of any other way to force the user to select a calling app ?

Comment: You could try to add that permission string in your manifest with `<uses-permission>`, but it may or may not work since it is a protected permission.  This is really breaking the Android `Intent` resolution paradigm, especially if the user has already selected what app they wish to always use to dial.  You'll want to be careful in considering whether to do this.  One of the big VoIP apps used to play games with this and constantly override the system - it was quickly uninstalled on my phone.  It's like getting a pop-up in a browser every time you do something: very annoying.

Comment: I had a feeling someone is going to say something about this here ;) 2 facts : 1. Im displaying it only under certain conditions. 2. When making a regular phone call from the device (not by clicking a url for example), there is no way to get the app chooser dialog ever. even when you clear the defaults in the device settings. You can consider this also as breakage of the android Intent resolution paradigm. Anyway, im going to try adding this permission and see how it goes. Thanks.

Comment: Didnt work. Also, i cannot just add this permission - "This permission is a signature level permission and we can only use it when the signature of my app will be same as the system".